# Remove TAB trigger from auto-complete

Tags: key-bindings, auto-complete-mode

If I set

```
(ac-set-trigger-key "C-o")
```

in `.emacs`, `C-o` does trigger auto-completion but TAB still does too. It seems that `C-o` is added to the triggers, while I want it to substitute TAB, so that when I press TAB no auto-completion is performed.

With YASnippet you can do something like:

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
```

So that the binding is removed, is there something similar for auto-complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto-complete` defines three keymaps that might be relevant here:

- `ac-mode-map`: This map is active when `auto-complete-mode` is enabled. `ac-set-trigger-key` adds the binding for the trigger key to this map.
- `ac-completing-map`: This map is active during completion. By default, `TAB` is bound to `ac-expand` in this map.
- `ac-menu-map`: This map is active while the popup showing possible completions is displayed (in addition to `ac-completing-map`), but only if `ac-use-menu-map` is set to a non-`nil` value.

If you want to make sure `TAB` won't do anything that's even remotely related to completion, you should probably "unset" the bindings in all of these maps (using the same technique you demonstrate for `yas-minor-mode-map` in your question).

---

**UPDATE**:

Here is a minimal configuration that keeps `TAB` from doing completion:

```el
(package-initialize)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(define-key ac-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map [tab] nil)
```

You can try it out by starting Emacs via `emacs -Q`, copying the code into the `*scratch*` buffer and running <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: thanks for your reply, after adding: `(define-key ac-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key ac-menu-map (kbd "TAB") nil)` to my .emacs file TAB still does trigger auto-completion. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @dcmst I added a minimal configuration that does what you want to my answer.

Comment: fyi for who is wondering: ‘-Q’
‘--quick’

    Start emacs with minimum customizations. This is similar to using ‘-q’, ‘--no-site-file’, ‘--no-site-lisp’, and ‘--no-splash’ together. This also stops Emacs from processing X resources by setting inhibit-x-resources to t (see Resources).


From: Emacs Manual: Initial Options